# A random HTML canvas element renders inside the app. Is there a way to inspect it inside React?

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas

I've been building a React application and suddenly when I was inspecting the mobile version, my app randomly created an HTML canvas element that covered my whole app like a modal.

I have no idea how to inspect the element. Specifically where it comes from. I've tried disabling components one by one, profiling in React dev tools to see what causes it, and many other things but nothing seemed to work.

It specifically occurs in a mobile version and it occurs on a random re-render of a any component. Sometimes the app can work fine and then you force some random component to re-render and it appears.

Is there a way to inspect where HTML element is coming from in React app? I have suspicion that a library is causing it, I tried disabling it too and it wouldn't work.

The canvas appears to have predetermined attributes. I've tried searching by attributes and nothing appears.

Below are my package.json dependencies in case something might cause it:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.16.4",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.46.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "stripe": "^11.8.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser's dev tools' DOM Mutation Breakpoints:

- [Firefox: Break on DOM Mutation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/break_on_dom_mutation/index.html)
- [Chrome: DOM breakpoints](https://blittle.github.io/chrome-dev-tools/elements/dom-breakpoints.html)